# Firebase object from getValue() is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`dataSnapshot.getValue()` returns `null` even though I am pretty sure that I am referring to correct path and there is a value for that key in my JSON tree. It was sent there like this : `dbreference.setValue(true);` .

Comment: Show the snipet of code that calls .getValue and also the dataSnaphot object.  It will easy for us to understand where is it going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not getting data correctly. Here is example code that I use to get data from firebase which may help you:

```
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("user_details").child("user_id").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = null, surname = null, email = null, phone = null, bd = null, gender = null;
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            if (child.getKey().equals("firstName")) {
                name = child.getValue().toString();
            }
            if (child.getKey().equals("lastName")) {
                surname = child.getValue().toString();
            }
            if (child.getKey().equals("birthday")) {
                bd = child.getValue().toString();
            }
            if (child.getKey().equals("email")) {
                email = child.getValue().toString();
            }
            if (child.getKey().equals("gender")) {
                gender = child.getValue().toString();
            }
            if (child.getKey().equals("phone")) {
                phone = child.getValue().toString();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you check my code here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310298/firebase-database-data-returning-null-when-reading?noredirect=1#comment69840848_41310298

Comment: You did not answer the question at all, which part of  your code you think OP didn't know/ do?

Comment: @ericn the user didn't post full code. So, I give my example code that how to get data from firebase without having issue.